# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Steven' to data type int

Tags: sql, int, type-conversion, varchar

Here are the codes

```
SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, COUNT(e.Employee_ID) AS '# of employees', AVG(e.Salary) AS 'AveSalary'
FROM employees e , departments d  
WHERE e.department_id = d.Department_ID  
GROUP BY d.Department_id, d.department_name
 UNION ALL
SELECT e.first_name,e.Last_Name, e.job_id,e.Salary
FROM employees e , departments d  
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id;
```

Comment: You should explain what you want to do.  And, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're `UNION`ing 2 datasets that have different column datatypes.

First part:
int, char, int, int

Second part:
char, char, int, int

When it does the union, it tries to resolve the conflict between the columns according to the [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx), so it's trying to convert the 1st column of the second query into an int datatype, which is where it's failing.

An immediate fix would be to cast the 1st column of the first query to a char like so:

```
SELECT CAST (d.department_id AS NVARCHAR(100)), d.department_name, COUNT(e.Employee_ID) AS '# of employees', AVG(e.Salary) AS 'AveSalary'
FROM employees e , departments d
WHERE e.department_id = d.Department_ID
GROUP BY d.Department_id, d.department_name

UNION ALL

SELECT e.first_name,e.Last_Name, e.job_id,e.Salary
FROM employees e , departments d
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciated your help! Thank you.

Comment: No worries, but as Gordon Linoff suggests, it's probably not the query that you want to run.
We could provide more help with proper context

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is the query you want:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.Last_Name, e.job_id, e.Salary,
       d.department_id, d.department_name,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.department_id) as NumEmployees
FROM employees e JOIN
     departments d
     ON e.department_id = d.department_id;
```

I see no (sensible) reason to put the department information in some rows and the employee information on others.

Comment: This is the link to the output that we are trying to achieve:    https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3c1oRuY8ScUcjBIQ1NCdWI3TGs/view?ts=588fde52     We can't seem to project the perfect output for the problem.

Comment: @VcutMan . . . You should ask another question.  That is not related to this question, as far as I can see.  You should include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked for help with this question, and I was taught this:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, COUNT(e1.employee_id) as 'Employees',
ISNULL(convert(varchar, avg(e1.salary)),'No Average') as avesal,
e2.last_name, e2.salary, e2.job_id
from Departments d, Employees e1, Employees e2
where d.Department_ID=e1.Department_ID
and d.Department_ID = e2.Department_ID
group by d.Department_ID, d.Department_Name, e2.Last_Name, e2.Salary, e2.Job_ID
order by d.Department_ID, employees
```

It's okay to have duplicate entries in the table, since in SQL, we can't have empty entries or those entries will be labeled null.

Again, this is what was answered in class.